# Casting (float) everywhere in C#. Is it better to just work in doubles?

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point, double

Working on an XNA game, I'm using float for most of my number values. Most C# functions seem to input/output doubles so I'm writing (float) a lot. Should I just be using Doubles or is how I'm working OK?

Comment: I think it's crazy that Java and .NET require an explicit cast from `double` to `float` but not the other way, since every cast of the best `double` representation of a numerical quantity to a `float` will yield either the best `float` representation of that quantity or is within one LSB of it.  By contrast, casting the best `float` representation of a quantity to `double` will often yield a result that's nowhere near the best `double` representation of that quantity, and may be off by hundreds of orders of magnitude (compare the effects of casting...

Comment: ...3.0E+38*2.0 to `float` (correctly compares greater than float.MaxValue), versus casting 3.0E+38f*2.0f to `double` (incorrectly compares greater than 1.0E+308).  Or, for a more common case, compare the correctness of `float f = (float)(1.0/10.0);` and `double d = 1.0f/10.0f;`.  The former style of assignment requires a cast, even though all such assignments will be essentially numerically correct.  The latter style doesn't require a cast, even though most such assignments are just plain wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using doubles. They are more accurate than single precision floats and there will be an overhead for casting.

Comment: Good advice in general, but XNA itself tends to prefer `float` (see, for example, the `MathHelper` class). Not sure why, probably because if you're copying and manipulating zillions of numbers (as you might be in a 3D game) then the perf difference between using a 32-bit `float` rather than a 64-bit `double` could be significant. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper_members.aspx

Comment: @LukeH - In that case I'd go with the type that results in the least casting. If you're making more XNA calls then go with float, but otherwise go with double.

Answer (score 2):

It's good to start with a default choice of `int` for integers, `double` for floating-point numbers and `decimal` for decimal-precise numbers. Then make changes to that choice either as an optimisation (`float` takes up less space than `double` so if you are storing a very large number of them that might be a reasonable choice), to better match some outside-imposed criteria, or because it won't suffice (i.e. when you need to use `long` rather than `int`).

Answer (score 1):

If performance is an issue you'll have to measure if the smaller memory footprint compensates for the cost of the casts, this will depend on how much casting you're doing.

If performance is not an issue I'd go with double to make code cleaner.